# jQuery Token Input Invalid JSON primitive

Tags: jquery-tokeninput

I'm using this plugin:
http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Initialized using

```
$("#actors").tokenInput("/Services/AutoComplete.asmx/AdminNames", {
            method: "post",
            theme: "facebook"
});
```

On typing in the input, I get this error in the NET tab of Firebug

```
500 Internal Server Error

Post - q=a
Response - {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: q.","StackTrace":" ...
JSON - "Invalid JSON primitive: q."
```

If I use a variable instead of Web Service, it works fine. I don't even get the debug control of the web service.

Thanks,
Dev

Comment: Do you know what you're web service is expecting? The error looks like the web service may be expecting a query in JSON, which isn't how the plugin works, and I'm not sure it can be easily adapted to do so. (This is probably not so useful over a year on, apologies.)